# Cordova wmic error

Tags: windows-10, cross-platform, apache-cordova

[I'm on windows 10 - Linux Mint Terra is working fine :) ]

when I try to create a cordova project I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\user\EvothingsStudio\MyApps>cordova create DemoProject com.evothings.demoapp DemoApp
```

[same error with `cordova create project`]

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\execa\index.js:347
                throw err;
                ^

Error: Command failed: wmic os get Caption
Der Befehl "wmic" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden.


at makeError (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
at Function.module.exports.sync (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\execa\index.js:338:15)
at windowsRelease (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\windows-release\index.js:34:24)
at osName (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\os-name\index.js:39:18)
at new Insight (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\insight\lib\index.js:37:13)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\src\telemetry.js:26:15)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:759:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:770:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:628:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:555:12)
```

Hope anybody has an idea how to solve this (creating an app with Evothings Studio 2.2.1 on Windows is working fine, and yes I use the command promopt with admin privileges :) )

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried many things, but I had to:

1. Windows-Key (Keyboard)
2. System Environment Variable / System Umgebungsvariable bearbeiten
3. Environmentsvariables.. / Umgebungsvariablen
4. Select Path Variable and edit
5. Add the path to your wbem
6. example: c:\Windows\System32\wbem
7. Restart cmd

Enjoy - ftw :)